# Is there a way to specify the background color only once using Materialize.css?

Tags: html, css, materialize

I'm using the following HTML with [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/) in an attempt to make a card with some contents have a dark background:

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
            

<div class="card grey darken-4 white-text">
  <h6>Title</h6>
  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

However, the result looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the text is unreadable because the text color is inherited by the `<ul>` items, but the background color is not. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or that this is a limitation of Materialize.

The only way I can get it to work is by explicitly specifying the background color *of every child element*, like so:

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


 <div class="card grey darken-4 white-text">
  <h6>Title</h6>
  <ul class="collection grey darken-4">
    <li class="collection-item grey darken-4">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item grey darken-4">
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item grey darken-4">
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This renders correctly, but it's ugly and doesn't work well with our templating system. Is there a way to specify the background color only once?

Comment: It because class `collection-item` in `collection` such as `.collection .collection-item` is applying a `background-color: white`. Just inspect. It is normal way. You can alway specify your own CSS

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a bug, just normal behave from the framework

Comment: Why would you close questions that aren't bugs?

Comment: You present it as if it would be a framework  problem. But this is very basic CSS question here... How to apply CSS to a child ? Do not really need to get more than the answer you got. Best regards

Comment: And your original title was: "Why are my Materialize.css background colors not cascading?", so as I said in my first comment it is very normal behaving.

Comment: If this is normal, Materialize.css violates the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F24.html

Comment: From the moment you are using a framework, that is not 100% surprising that it has its own behave. Bootstrap has some similar behave. This is up-to-you to make it has you wish after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual class, from materialize.css is:

```
.collection .collection-item {
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

You can check this by inspecting the element. Lots of workarounds for amending to your requirements. You can use the built in utility color classes like this:

```
.collection .collection-item {
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

and then:

```
<ul class="collection grey darken-4">
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 3
    </li>
</ul>
```

Declare the bg color once on the ul, then globally all collection li's will take on this bg color too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use CSS and style the `.collection-item` class?

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
<style>
.card > ul > .collection-item {
  background-color: #212121 !important;
}
</style>    

<div class="card grey darken-4 white-text">
  <h6>Title</h6>
  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="collection-item">
      Item 3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dangerous to do so, because it means that it will change all behave class on the whole website, probably this is not the best... But you could precise it by adding an id to the `div.card` and then specify CSS from there

Comment: @MaxiGui I've updated my answer. You could call it specifically with something like this `.card > ul > .collection-item`